# No `Podfile' found in the project directory with existing Podfile

Tags: flutter, macos, installation, cocoapods, apple-m1

I'm developing an app in Flutter and macOS Monterey (M1). It's done for Android and I was attempting in IOS. But I have this error when I run flutter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xhSzA.png)

Terminal commands:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h14Qz.png)

Podfile seems like that:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OqgB.png)

Comment: you should install pod

Comment: Try uninstalling and re-installing cocoapods

Answer (score 4):

You need to `cd` into the `ios` directory like so

`cd ios`

and then run the following command if you have cocoapods installed

`pod install`

If you do not have cocoapods installed on your machine, you can install it using the following command.

`sudo gem install cocoapods`.

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

open your .zshrc file and paste this

> ```
> export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
> export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
> export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
> ```

after pasting save it and exit your terminal and then restart your editor and then run again

Comment: It still gives the same problem... Changing the language to es_ES warns of the language and fails, but with en_US it simply gives an error. I have already reinstalled cocoapods in all possible ways, and in fact the problem does not seem to be in the installation because pod init does work...

Comment: did you restart your IDE? after adding the changes?

Comment: Yes, IDE and terminal. Changes are done cause echo $LANG get the changes right

Comment: well you actually need to restart everything to test it i faced the same  two months ago after getting a new m1 and after adding the above code it didn't fix until i manually restarted everything before it worked

Comment: Still the issue:
CocoaPods'output:
↳
 [!] No `Podfile' found in the project directory.
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:161:in `verify_podfile_exists!'
 /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:46:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run' /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.11.3/bin/pod:55:in `<top(required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'